# jQuery Spinner intercept double click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a option picker. Now there is a new requirement to have the options be configurable. while that is not a big problem, the option picker makes me trouble:

When an item is double clicked it will get selected/unselected. If selected, the configuration options will show. While this works fine with standard HTML elements like checkboxes, i can't get it to work like intended with jQuery spinners.

In the following snippet, i simulate the effect of unselecting the elment turning it red instead. So go on and try to change the spinner value via the up+down buttons without the label turning red.

As you can see, this works fine on the checkboxes, which can be changed checked/unchecked as fast as you want, without turning the label red. The spinner however will turn the label red, if your'e clicking too fast, triggering the double click event.

How can the doubleclick event be propperly catched?

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var $item = $(".item");
  
  $item.disableSelection()
  $item.on("dblclick",function(){
    $(this).addClass("marker");
  });
  $item.find("input").on("dblclick",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("input[type='text']").spinner({min:1});
  $("input[type='button']").on("click",function(){
    $(".marker").removeClass("marker");
  });
});
```

```css
.marker {
  color:red;
}
.item {
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
input[type='text'] {
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div class="item"><input type="text" value="1"> some labeling text</div>
<div class="item"><input type="checkbox"> some labeling text </div>
<div class="item"><input type="checkbox"> some labeling text </div>

<input type="button" value="reset">
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i figured it out myself,

```
$item.find("input, span:has(input)").on("dblclick",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

did the trick, since the problem is the wrapper that's added by jQuery